Syllables of noun ‹cavalier›?
Salut,
Analyzing French pronunciation, the following question occured to me:
Which, precisely, are the syllables in pausal standard French pronunciation of the noun ‹cavalier› ?
Is it [ka.va.ˈlje] or [ka.val.ˈje] ?
Note that the matter is clear when using [ʎ] instead of [lj]. My question only applies when using [lj] instead of [ʎ]. Can [lj] be distributed among syllables?

I think the first one. Ca.va.lier. It's not comfortable to have a -ier syllable for me.

As for me, I prefer [l̺ˠ.je], as opposed to [.lje]. However, question is not about individual preferences.

What is pausal standard French pronunciation?

@Lambie: When I say 'pausal' with regard to pronunciation, it means 'pronounced in isolation'—as opposed to 'pronunciation in non-empty context', which may include liaison or a different stress pattern, particularly in French.

Ok, well, pronounced as a single word versus in connected speech. I had never seen pausal like that, which is why I asked.

In linguistic writings, I encountered a term 'in pausa'. Although the latter seems to refer to 'pronunciation preceding a pause' (thus excluding liaison), I use 'pausal' in the sense specified above. What I like about 'pausal' is its shortness.

@checkerscheck But one downside is that at face value, it's a little misleading, maybe. One thinks about pauses while saying a whole text, rather than thinking about a word in isolation. Although, granted, if you make a pause before and after the word, it's isolated.

I agree. 'Pausal' is trade-off between concision and precision.

Correction: 'pausa' and 'in pausa', in linguistics, doesn't mean 'pronunciation before  pause'. It's much more involved, relating to prosodic units in general and (vowel) hiatus. Still, I use 'pausal' in the above-specified sense.

Like I said above, a single word versus a word in connected speech: parole connectée. Liaison for example is one feature of parole connectée in French. You can say pausa, but it is not usual in this context.

You have probably noticed that the translation in French of an English text is significantly longer than the original text. however when pronounced, the duration of the 2 is similar. Mainly because French speakers speak with a very even rhythm, giving an equal amount of stress to practically every syllable and word. Therefore, it's difficult to identify the position of the break between syllables. This is easier in English because intonation (tone, stress, pause, ...) matters more.

In poetry, both syllable counts (and the differing pronounciations) are legal; however, ca-va-li-er (technically, a diaeresis) is not standard in modern French and, unless the author has a specific phonetic effect in mind, will sound awkward.

Baudelaire famously dared the effect in reverse in Fleurs du mal. The most charitable I can say is, it's not a hit. The verse is: De la mâle Sapho, qui fut amante et poète. Nobody counts poète as 1 syllable, which would require to pronounce it pouett.

The title song in Disney's Zorro for the French TV starts with Un cavalier... Definitely 3 syllables: https://youtu.be/z8vnBbPwZvE?t=15

When breaking words into syllables the rule¹ is that when a consonant is between two vowels (or between a vowel and a semi vowel) then the consonant starts a new syllable.
According to the rule ca/va/lier [ka.va.lje] would be the usual pronunciation. When saying poetry or in songs one might need to add an extra syllable and break it thus: [ka.va.li.je].

¹ How to break words into syllables in French.

Could well be the answer. I'm not accepting just yet though. Maybe someone comes up with a more scientifc source.

The conclusion is correct in this case, but that source is a bad one, it has several examples that are dubious or outright wrong. For example, with two identical consonant, there is almost never (not “always”) a break between the two — gemmination is rare in French, and pomme rhymes with tome, tasse with lace, terre is a homophone of taire (except in dialects that have a long [ɛ:]?), apprendre is a homophone of à prendre, etc. @checkerscheck

French tends to dislike syllables that end in a consonant. Use that as the default rule. There are considerable variations between speakers, and many speakers are not fully consistent depending on whether they are speaking carefully or casually, or they can have free variations. But you can speak French without ever ending a syllable in a consonant, and in most cases you would not be wrong, just reflecting a particular native accent.

Inside a word, if there is a consonant between two vowel sounds, group the consonant with the following vowel. That is really a rule followed by all speakers.
Inside a word, you can place a consonant cluster entirely in the following syllable in fast speech. In carefully enunciated speech, that doesn't work so well for consonants that are prolonged, such as /ʁ/, /l/, /s/, /z/: if you hold these consonants for a while before starting the next consonant, the prolonged consonant sticks with the previous vowel. (Although arguably it might be analyzed as a separate syllable.) Example: [pas·tis] is the normal pronunciation, but [pa·stis] is also possible when speaking quickly.
The consonant /l/ in particular really likes to be followed by a vowel if it isn't prolonged, or by a true consonant (not a semivowel) if it is.
If a word ends with a consonant sound, and there is no pause after the word, move that consonant to the next word. This rule is so strong that even in words that ended with a consonant but no longer do in modern French, the consonant is still voiced when the next word starts with a vowel sound without a pause – that's a liaison.
If a word cluster ends with a consonant sound, add a small schwa /ə/, even in words that don't end with a “silent e” in writing. It's more prevalent in the south of France (just like pronouncing actual silent e's), where the rendition is closer to [ø̜], but it's also a common free variation of many speakers with more northern accents.

Once again, this is a bit extreme and I doubt that anyone speaks like this all the time. But you would always be pronouncing French the way some natives pronounce some of the time.

It is syllabified as [ka.va.lje] (I omitted the stress marker since stress is not a contrastive feature of French phonology).
Compare the transcription [kɔ̃.si.lje] on page 13 of this paper: "Variable Glide Formation in Hexagonal French" (2015), by Stephanie A. Kelly,  Electronic Thesis and
Dissertation Repository. 2702.
French allows syllables to start with a consonant + [j] and it tends to prefer this syllabification over putting [j] at the start of its own syllable (even though [j] can occur at the start of its own syllable in cases where there is no alternative syllabification, such as when [j] comes after a vowel, or when it is pronounced at the start of an utterance).

I think the standard separation in syllables is:

ca.va.lier

This website may help: https://www.separarensilabas.com/index-fr.php

When breaking words into syllables the rule is that when a consonant is between two vowels (or here between a vowel and a semi vowel) then the consonant starts a new syllable.  More reliable than a mere syllabe breaker.

@Frank: The site you link to, is it about orthographic syllables or phonetic, e.g. articulatory, ones ? What I'm concerned here with is articulatory syllables.

@checkerscheck Hmm good point. I think it's orthographic syllables.

We are all here to learn something, aren't we ? (Except those driven by commercial motives, of course.)
